# How to find the number of papers per language written by a researcher?

Tags: publications

Is there any fast way to find the number of papers per language written by a given researcher?

E.g., researcher John Doe published 30 papers written in English, 16 papers written in Spanish, and 3 papers written in German.

By fast, I mean faster than going on Google Scholar and counting the number of paper for each language  oneself.

Comment: This is actually a data analytics problem. This should either be supplied by the author page or be done with a help of a customised analytics tool.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Does it mean it's off-topic here? I have always been confused by the scope of this exchange website regarding software question. http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/174/452 says it's on-topic but close votes are quite random.

Comment: Well I guess I'll leave the question here then

Comment: Let's hope author indexing site like Google Scholar would implement this one day and then you may receive an answer post to this question.

Answer (score 1):

[Clarivate's Web of Science](https://www.webofknowledge.com) citation database can provide this information. Assuming you have access to it, e.g. through your institution, you can

1. Search for a researcher's name
2. If necessary, use additional criteria to try to restrict the results to a single person
3. Look under "More options" for languages.

While this option is mainly intended for further restricting the search results, the tool also tells you the number of articles in language X associated with researcher name Y. Of course, their database [coverage](https://clarivate.libguides.com/webofscienceplatform/coverage) has some restrictions, so it may or may not work for your purposes. In certain fields, other databases could be more useful.

---

[image]